# What should I do if I disagree with established policy?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

For example, suppose that I think a certain class of questions should be off-topic, but it has been thoroughly established on my site's meta that they're on-topic.

If someone posts a new question in this class, should I vote to close it? If so, should I explain my vote in a comment? If I do, should I just say "I think this is off-topic because...", or should I also somehow mention what the actual policy/consensus is?

To be clear: my intention here is *not* to discuss the policy in question at all, but just to get an idea what one should do in situations like this from the broader community (and from people with no interest in the policy).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the rest of the community has decided that this type of question is on topic then you're really just wasting your vote by voting to close. You're also sending confusing signals to the users who post these questions.

If you don't agree with something then your options are basically:

- Just ignore the questions and look for others to answer.
- Re-open the debate on your site's meta to get the site's scope changed to make these questions off topic. This could be a counter productive move, unless you can muster really good arguments for your position.
- Leave the site (NOTE: I really hope you don't do this, I'm just adding it for completeness).

Personally, I'd go with the first option.

What you shouldn't do is go complaining about the policy elsewhere. That's not fair to the other members of the community who might not be able to respond.

Comment: What do you think about the idea that voting is based on personal opinion, so community consensus shouldn't be used to stop people from voting the way they feel is correct?

Comment: @Jefromi I did consider that, but with something like closing as off topic I think there's less leeway.

Comment: @Jefromi: if everyone votes on what they *think* shouldn't be there, although meta says it is, it would be unfair to the one posting the question and taking the time to comply to the site's policy.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Even if they explain in a comment, "I think it's off-topic because X" so that it's obviously just their opinion?

Comment: @Jefromi: what if the user deletes his question because of that or doesn't asks a similar question next time? Such discussions are for meta, nowhere else.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Deletion seems pretty extreme, in response to a close vote and an opinion, and it's not really a discussion, just an explanation. (Better than not explaining, right?)

Comment: I have seen a lot of people deleting their question after 1 or 2 downvotes or close votes (if made public).

Comment: @PatrickHofman I have to confess, I've been playing devil's advocate here, I totally agree with both you and ChrisF here. I'd continue, but it's starting to feel way too much like trolling.